# Where can i find iOS 5 frameworks to add to a project?

Tags: ios

i have the latest XCode 4.5.2 with all the iOS6 framework installed.
But i want to create projects available for iOS 5, 5.1 and 6.

I have added MapKit Framework but i can only choose iOS 6 frameworks.

Is there a place to download old frameworks to make application available to everyone ?
or may this iOS 6 Framework works on 5.0 projects ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your deployment target to 5.0. Make sure to weak reference the Frameworks that are relevant only for iOS 6.0, if there are any.

Comment: yes i have put Deployment Target to 5.0 but when i had a Library via Link Library in Build Phases, i can only find IOS6 libraries .. does it matter or should i really have ios5.0 libraries there ?

Answer (score 0):

Go to cocoapods.org it's a script that will download and install external frameworks to your project. You can even set the version of iOS you are using.